# Is there any way to include Solspace Calendar events in a global site search?

Tags: plugin-solspacecalendar

I have a client that wants their Solspace Calendar Events to show up in the global site search results (along with entries from other sections)

My first thought was to query the entries and calendar events separately, merge the result sets together, and then paginate them. Basically this: [Merge Craft entries and Venti events in search results](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21854/merge-craft-entries-and-venti-events-in-search-results)

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: were you able to find a resolution for this? I'm in a similar boat, where the client wants everything from Craft and Solspace Calendar in the global search results.

Comment: @thescottallen Nope. It's easy enough to merge the results together, and output them, but it doesn't work with pagination. You could implement pagination manually, but it's a lot of screwing around. Additionally I couldn't find a way to merge based on relevance score, So, events either appear at the start or the end of the results.

In the end I added a another loop on the first page of results which search for events, it shows up to three events, and if there are any more, it renders a link to a separate event search page.